# Can access only one item using QTreeWidget::itemAt

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

I have a QTreeWidget declared as following

```
QTreeWidget * datasiftIdpwTree;
datasiftIdpwTree->setColumnCount(2);
datasiftIdpwTree->headerItem()->setText(0, "Username");
datasiftIdpwTree->headerItem()->setText(1, "Api Key");
```

it is filled with data using the following slot

```
void Window::addDatasiftIdpw(QString username, QString apikey)
{
    datasiftIdpwTree->addTopLevelItem(new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList(username) << apikey));
}
```

I can live view the slot addind data to my tree, the probleme is when accessing the data.
I tried using

```
datasiftIdpwTree->itemAt(x,y)->text(0);
```

but however the value of x, y I use, it always point to the first item (the one produced when first calling addDatasiftIdpw)
Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: `itemAt` is for viewport coordinates, are using those?

Comment: I indeed messed up betwen itemAt(i,0) and topLevelItem(i)

Comment: Please do not use SOLVED tags either in title or text. If you found solution to your problem yourself, just add your own answer through form bellow and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made made a mistake between cooridnates and index. Accessing the i-th element is achived by:

```
datasiftIdpwThree->topLevelItem(i)->text(0);
```